# How does 'distributed tracker' concept work in Bittorrent DHT?

Tags: protocols, bittorrent, dht

I have read [Kademila spec](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/~petar/papers/maymounkov-kademlia-lncs.pdf) and [DHT BEP for Bittorent](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html) but still can't understand how DHT makes trackerless torrents reliable. 
My understanding of routing procedure is:

- Node (say A) picks node with id closest to infohash of torrent from its routing table (say B) and sends find_peers query to it
- If B doesn't have information about peers it sends addresses of nodes with id closer to infohash
- Node A makes iterative routing until it reaches node (say X) that responds with seeding peers addresses
- When node A starts download process node A announces it to node X

But what happens when node X vanishes from swarm? Is there any failover? How tracking information are distributed across nodes in swarm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the DHT is a global overlay shared between all bittorrent clients, it's not specific to individual swarms.

Second, straight from the paper, section 2.3:

> To store a (key,value) pair, a participant locates the ***k*** closest nodes
>   to the key and sends them storE RPCs. Additionally, each node
>   re-publishes (key,value) pairs as necessary to keep them alive, as
>   described later in Section 2.5 . This ensures persistence (as we show
>   in our proof sketch) of the (key,value) pair with very high
>   probability.